# Can I pass values from one feature file of one folder to another feature file of another folder under /src/java/test using karate dsl

Tags: dsl, karate

My project structure is something like this:

```
/src/java/test

TestRunner -> main.java
Component1 --> Admin.feature
Component2 --> Publisher.feature
Component3 --> Store.feature
```

I want to pass some value from `Admin.feature` file to `Publisher.feature` file.
Is that possible?

I know we can pass values from one feature file to another under the same folder, but I'm unsure if the value can be used throughout my folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you are able to `read()` your feature file and both the features are in the same scenario.

Let's say you want to pass values from `Admin` to `Publisher` inside a `Store` feature.

Store.feature

```
Scenario:
    * def getAdmin = call read('classpath:Component1/Admin.feature') {"SomeInput":"toAdmin"}
    * def getPublisher = call read('classpath:Component2/Publisher.feature') {"Admin": "#(getAdmin.response)"}
```

now inside your `Publisher.feature` you can get the admin response details in the `Admin` varaible

Note: To find any file under /src/java/test directory you can prefix with `classpath:` as mentioned in the above example.

Lets say I have multiple scenariosinside my called feature (with tags=@scenario) and I only want to run scenario1. Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: This works but every time i call the other feature , it executes the feature steps again and then gives the newly generated values of the variables. What i really want is , call another feature and fetch the last saved value from that feature . Is that possible?

Comment: @sneha If you want to run any feature only on time instead of using call use callonce, then it will not rerun and you will get the last generated value only

Comment: * def getAdmin = callonce read('classpath:Component1/Admin.feature') {"SomeInput":"toAdmin"}

Comment: So if I do * def getAdmin = callonce read('classpath:Component1/Admin.feature') {"SomeInput":"toAdmin"}  once and then do * def getAdmin = call read('classpath:Component1/Admin.feature') {"SomeInput":"toAdmin"} at other places where i want to use it, then the second statement is going to just call the feature and take the last generated values ?

Comment: if you want to use the value of your Admin feature in multiple scenarios inside a feature, you can keep the callonce step in the background and it will execute first time only and cache the value for rest of the scenarios

Comment: Cool Thanks a lot

Comment: @BabuSekaran - Is it possible to reference a feature file in another maven project directory which is within the same workspace through the use of read() ? I would like to re-use an authentication feature throughout multiple projects but would like to only write the log in feature once rather than in multiple places throughout my project.

Comment: It should work as long as that external maven project is added as a maven dependency for your current project and the file is kept in its classpath. And use read('classpath:file_name') to read that file